# Why is my listview not expanding to accommodate a larger row size?

Tags: android

I have a listview that I want the user to be able to delete items from. If the user holds on a row long enough, the row's checkbox is made visible. However, the listview doesn't grow to accommodate the (now taller) row despite there being plenty of space. I had this issue before when the listview was in a scrollview but that's no longer the case. I understand I can reformat the text as a bandage solution, but I want to understand what is happening.

Here is the listview before and after the first entry is held. You can see the listview's height stays the same and doesn't expand to accommodate the two entries:

[image: ListView with two entries]

[image: ListView after holding the first entry, making the the checkbox visible]

Here is the listView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is the listView item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns="https://"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/deleteCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how the layout is being inflated in my custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomlistEntry> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomlistEntry> entries) {
        super(context, 0, entries);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_listview, parent, false);
        }
        CustomlistEntry entry = getItem(position);

        TextView tvNumber = convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        TextView tvDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        tvNumber.setText(entry.getNumber());
        tvDate.setText(entry.getDateString());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and finally the adapter being set:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(App.getApp(), arrayListSorted);
final ListView listView = activity.findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       final int pos, long id) {
            arg1.findViewById(R.id.deleteCheckBox).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
            return true;
        }
    });
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hi @Jaitnium, seems like the CheckBox occupied some space causing the 2 TextView to wrap its text content. I suggest that you add a property to that 2 TextView to be a singleline TextView.

Comment: @jase I understand that the text is wrapping, but I don't understand what you mean by adding a property to make the textviews a single line.